# Performing PCA with results of multiple other PCAs? Is this legit, how do I interpret it?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, subset

I'm a biology researcher, working on a manuscript that involves folks from outside of my discipline. They are using PCA to create indices of demographic variables, to categorize geographic areas. For one of the cases, they actually used subsets of the variables, ran 3 separate PCAs, and then used the results of those analyses as data to run another PCA.

This seems like a reasonable technique from a mathematical standpoint, but I have no idea how to interpret the results, at least in terms of the contribution from the underlying original data attributes.

Also, I'm just completely unfamiliar with this approach. It's very different than how I've used PCA previously. I'm wondering how established doing something like this is, and if there's any literature I could read about it, or just examples of it that I could look at.

Comment: are the folks you're working with engineers, by any chance? This sounds exactly like something they would do lmao. Re literature: My gut says it's going to be hard finding literature describing this. Re interpretation: Since the composition of linear projections is linear, you can recover the loadings of these "second order" components by plugging in the loadings from the "first order" PCA if that helps interpretation.

Comment: Nope, they are social scientists. It's interesting working with them, because they just think about things very differently, including some of the same stats techniques I've used.

Comment: They obviously did not want any of the predictors or final variables to be correlated, since PCA results in orthogonal variables (PC scores) with exactly zero correlation.